# Javadoc @throws tags for Exceptions thrown by error code handler

Tags: java, exception, javadoc

I am bridging a C Api to a Java Api. The C Api uses error codes for exceptional cases. Since every function returns such a error code and there are a lot of error codes (about 100), i wrote a error code handler that translates the error codes to a bunch of more general runtime exceptions:

```
public class ErrorCodeHandler {
    public static void handle(int status) {
        switch(status) {
            case SUCCESS:
                return; // In case of success, simply return
            case NO_VALID_DATA:
                throw new DataError("No valid data");
            ...
            case NO_CONNECTION:
                throw new ConnectionError("No connection");
        }
    }
}
```

All my custom Exception classes inherit from a base Exception class specific to my application:

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException { ... }
public class DataException extends MyException { ... }
...
```

My methods simply call handle on the error code returned from the call to the C API:

```
public void someMethod() {
    int status = cBinding.someMethod();
    ErrorCodeHandler.handle(status);
}
```

If an error occured, the method will throw the appropriate exception. If not, it will simply return.

Now i am faced with the problem on how to document this kind of exception handling. I read that you don't add runtime exceptions as a throws clause, but document it using the Javadoc @throws tag.

Now my question is, should i add a @throws tag for every different exception i know can be thrown from a method (indirectly by looking up the possible error codes), or should i just document a generic @throws MyException? I feel like the first approach will clutter my documentation with a lot of mostly useless @throws tags (a lot of these error codes are very rare) and it will be a very high effort to document these. The second approach would be mostly copy-pasting, but i would lose the advantage the exception hierarchy gives me.

Has anyone ever done something similar? Any advice on how to document this kind of stuff?

Comment: Any advice on how to document this kind of stuff? - are talking about javadocs here

Comment: Yeah, i will add the tag!

Comment: anyways i did that

Comment: From your code it looks like each method/function can throw all of the exceptions, is that the case? Usually methods/functions throw a subset of exceptions.

Comment: It can, if the right error code is returned from the C API. In practice the functions only return specific error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly reasonable to just write something like `@throws MyException if underlying service fails` in your javadoc.  It’s fairly common in Java SE;  for example:

- [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) only has `@throws` clauses for IOException and two subclasses of IOException, even though it can throw many other subclasses of IOException.
- The JDBC method [Statement.execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) has a `@throws` clause for SQLException and one subclass of SQLException, even though there are many other subclasses of SQLException that can be thrown.

Comment: I will do the same thing then and document the general exception and specific exceptions if they are likely to arise.